# Getting Array to string conversion while using React with Cart

Tags: reactjs, axios, cart

I use `react-use-cart` package in `react`.

Here is my function is:

```
const { items, cartTotal } = useCart(); 
const lists = items.map(item => item.id);
function handleSave(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     const order = {
       user_id: customer.id,
       order_date: date,
       amount: cartTotal,
       product_list: items
     };
     saveOrder(order)
       .then(() => {window.location.href = `/account/orders`})
       .catch(error => {});
}
```

Items added to cart are in the following format:

```
items: [
  {id:9,quantity:2,...},
  {id:24,quantity:1,...},
]
```

**How to assign this items to a const order into product_list?.** When I put only **items** prints the message: "Array to string conversion". Maybe I'm doing something the wrong way.

Comment: Can you show the code you tried that resulted in the "Array to string conversion" error message ? The `react-use-cart` package has `setItems` and `addItem` function available to use, did you use that ?

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam This message occurs when I press the Place Order button and display this error in the console tab. addItem I used to add the product to the cart. setItem I didn't use anywhere

Comment: Can you show the code relating to your Place Order button ?

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam  <form onSubmit={handleSave}>
                            <button type="submit" disabled={saving} className="btn btn-block rounded-pill btn-secondary">
                                {saving ? "PLACING ORDER..." : "PLACE ORDER"}
                            </button>
                        </form>

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam Or if you want me to set up the whole document, Checkout.js page